# Take Picture With webcam in Lotus Notes

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, webcam, lotusscript, lotus-formula

Sorry in advance if this is a really stupid question but I have recently started IBM notes(domino designer for my new job), I did not realize I will struggle so much. So my first task is to create a form that will be able click a picture and embed it straight into a rich-text format holder. Been looking into it for nearly a week still nowhere near. All I can do is launch the windows camera to click a picture and then select it with an opendialogue command but the task is that I have to do it automatically like the user will open up a cam and once clicks the pic, the pic will be embedded straight into the rich text format. Any kind of tips/tutorial or idea is welcomed. Really struggling. Below is the shellcode that I am using to launch the windows camera inside the form to click the picture.
p.s Apologies if my question standard or explanation was poor, English is not my first language also posting on stack overflow for the first time, I will edit the question if needed for anyone else in future.

Dim i as variant 
i = Shell("start microsoft.windows.camera:")

Comment: Hi, see this https://www.grange.com.br/posts/lotusscript-code-to-embed-a-picture-into-a-notes-richtext-item/ as an example on how to import the a picture in a richtext item. This would be done in the backend. With the help of the windows clipboard you might be able to paste the image in a currently open notesuidocument.
You can also use COM objects directly from Lotusscript with the createobject method.

Comment: I think you're going to need to embed an ActiveX control that can access your webcam. My PC doesn't seem to have one installed, but that doesn't mean that such a thing doesn't exist.

Comment: Just google for an example how to take the picture in Visual Basic. You can use basically the same code in Lotusscript except replacing Object by Variant and converting named parameters to unnamed (right order is important). You already got an example how to attach the taken picture to richtext... done

Comment: You might also explore if you can access the camera using Java.  That might open up another avenue for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the help, above mentioned solution would be really awesome if i had to the time to implement them, but here a really simple implementation in Javascript for anyone coming up in future and looking into it [link](https://github.com/noobsmatr619/IBM-Notes-Camera-LotusScript-Javascript)